# Counting Data based on Cover_Type using pandas

Tags: pandas, entropy

I have the following data in the excel sheet![image]

I need to count the number of times a given elevation occurs for a given cover_type. For example, elevation=1905 occurs twice for cover_type=6 and once for cover_type=3. I need to do the same Aspect, Slope, Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology, Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology, Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways, Hillshade_9am, Hillshade_Noon, Hillshade_3pm, Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points, Soil, Wilderness_Area.

I will be using the count to calculate the entropy of the each column. I need to execute this formula. [image]

Comment: it looked like he just picked random tags. for example [tag:eclipse] - the question doesn't mention eclipse. But I overlooked the pandas hidden in the title.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, I did make a mistake by tagging eclipse. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv')
grouped = df[['elevation','cover_type']].groupby(['elevation','cover_type'], as_index = False, sort = False)['cover_type'].count()
```

Comment: I tried you code and hit a snag :(

`pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
`

I googled and was not able to get the exact solution to this. Could you help?